# Trigger to send email based on Multi-Select Picklist

Tags: apex, trigger, email, lookup, multi-select

I have an object called `Project__c`. It has a multi select picklist field called `Markets__c`.

So a `Project` can have multiple `Markets`. On the other side, `Contact` object has a field called `Market__c`.

I need to have a trigger to send an email to each `Contact` record where `Project__c.Markets__c` field contains the value of `Contact.Market__c`.

Comment: I tried to create junction objects and multiple lookup relationships but it doesn't work since i have 36 markets over the limit of 25.

Comment: I don't know if it is possible to capture those contact with a query within a trigger

Comment: are Contacts related in any way in your schema to Project__c?  Is your requirement to send email to all contacts associated with a given market when a project for said-same market is Saved?  And a given Project can be for multiple markets but a contact is associated with only one market?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a fairly simple query.

```
public static List<Contact> getMarketContacts(List<Project__c> projects)
{
    Set<String> markets = new Set<String>();
    for (Project__c project : projects)
    {
        if (String.isNotBlank(Project__c.Markets__c))
            markets.addAll(Project__c.Markets__c.split(';'));
    }
    return [
        SELECT Email FROM Contact
        WHERE Market__c IN :markets
        LIMIT 50000
    ];
}
```

Then you just need to define the method to send emails, whose stub would look like:

```
public static void sendEmails(List<Contact> contacts)
{
    // logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way - use apex trigger and soql to save values from the picklist on create/edit and then query the object contacts to send emails.

Second way (better one) - don't create a picklist on project_c. Instead create an object that holds all value for markets. Then form the following lookup relations:
1. Lookup from market__c to project__c
2. Lookup from contact to market__c

What u have now is a 3 level relaionship. A workflow or a trigger should now work.

lemme knw what you think.
Mann.

Comment: I also wanted to create an object to hold all values for markets. But Project__c.Markets__c is Multi-Select Picklist field which has 40 values. How can I do that?

Comment: Why dont you create an object now? Just use dataloader to create the 40 enteries to the custom object

Answer (score 0):

From a DB design perspective and from what Ive understood your design should be as follows:

```
> {Markets}--{Jn}--{Projects}
>        | {Contact}
```

(Contact is the child of markets)

Now to send the email to contacts who are in markets which have a project (this is my understanding of your requirement), do the following: pseudocode begins:-

1. Query object Jn and get all Market names in a list (ie. Select market__c.name from jn group by market__c)
2. Query Contact object where contact.market__c IN list from step1
3. Send email to these contacts